# formspree.io "Make sure you open this page through a web server ..."

Tags: forms, email, post, action

I'm trying to use formspree.io but for some reason is returning the following error:

> Make sure you open this page through a web server, Formspree will not work in >pages browsed as HTML files. Also make sure that you're posting to >https://formspree.io/test@yopmail.com.
>
> For geeks: could not find the "Referrer" header.

My code is the following:

```
        <form action="https://formspree.io/test1@yopmail.com" method="POST" target="_blank">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="*First Name">

          <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="*Last Name">

          <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="*Your Message" style="height:200px"></textarea>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Please notice that I have the s in the "https://fo..." and I also have in my head tag the following:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have `test1@yopmail.com` instead of `test@yopmail.com`. I have no idea if that matters. The error message says to make sure that your web page is being run on a web server. Is it?

Comment: Is not the email, I it doesn't matter if I use test or test1. In reality I'm trying  my own personal email like (myemail)@hotmail.com. The error is always the same.

Comment: Did you miss the question I asked?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry. You were right. The problem was because it really needed to be running in a web server and I was testing only on a html page. Basically I just did put the project inside Visual Studio, adapted, run it and it is working. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the error when using a web server... I'm using django...